# Post-processing after completion of Splitter

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to create an integration flow where the following actions will be performed:

1. Call a http rest endpoint based on a cron expression to get a json response of a list of files and associated properties (like timestamp and others).
2. Transform the response to Java model (FileInfo (containing list of FileProperties)) using a custom object mapper.
3. Use a service activator to find the FileProperties with today's timestamp, if no such file then the flow stops here.
4. Output from the above is used to construct a http outbound gateway to do another http rest call to get the text file content.
5. The content is feed into a splitter to split the content into lines.
6. Then another transformer is used to convert each line into a Java model.
7. Then a JPA outbound gateway is used to persist that into DB.
8. Finally another http rest call need to be made to delete the file from the server.

I have devised a rough integration flow up to step 7:

```
<bean id="jsonToFilenamesMapper"/>
<bean id="sampleFileSplitter"/>
<bean id="dateBasedFilter"/>
<bean id="customMapper"/>
<bean id="em"/>
<bean id="randomCronTrigger"/>
<bean id="sampleFileNameSplitter"/>
<bean id="sampleFileActivator"/>

<int:channel id="input"/>
<int:channel id="output"/>
<int:channel id="filenames"/>
<int:channel id="reply"/>
<int:channel id="csvout"/>
<int:channel id="line"/>
<int:channel id="extractModel"/>
<int:channel id="afterSaving"/>
<int:channel id="filename"/>

<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="input"
                           reply-channel="output"
                           url=" https://download.com/files/"
                           http-method="GET"
                           expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="input" expression="''">
    <int:poller trigger="randomCronTrigger">
    </int:poller>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:json-to-object-transformer input-channel="output"
                                output-channel="filenames"
                                type="sample.integration.FileInfo"
                                object-mapper="jsonToFileInfoMapper">
</int:json-to-object-transformer>

<int:service-activator ref="sampleFileActivator"
                       input-channel="filenames"
                       output-channel="filename">
</int:service-activator>

<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="reply"
                           reply-channel="csvout"
                           url=" https://download.com/files/{filename}"
                           http-method="GET"
                           expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
    <int-http:uri-variable name="filename" expression="payload.filename"/>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<int:splitter input-channel="csvout"
              output-channel="line"
              ref="sampleFileSplitter">
</int:splitter>

<int:json-to-object-transformer input-channel="line"
                                output-channel="extractModel"
                                object-mapper="customMapper">
</int:json-to-object-transformer>

<int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway request-channel="extractModel"
                                   reply-channel="afterSaving"
                                   persist-mode="PERSIST"
                                   entity-manager="em">
</int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway>
```

So my questions are:

1. How should I implement step 8, I need to know that all lines are saved to DB before calling the http endpoint to delete the file.
2. Is the above flow looks right for requirement or there is opportunity to simplify?
3. How does the above flow will look using Java configuration/DSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks nice. You go the correct way.

I'd make an output channel of the splitter as an `ExecutorChannel` to let splitted items to be processed in parallel.

Your JPA gateway should send reply to the aggregator. And only aggregator will perform file deletion. Since you have a splitter before, then it will be just enough to rely on aggregator's defaults.

I don't see any obstacles to represent your flow via Java DSL. Advantages will be less code and no extra channels. Although even with this xml config you can come up for simplification with a `<chain>`.

Comment: So step 8 could be like this: 

`<int:aggregator input-channel="extractModel"
                    output-channel="postCompletion">
    </int:aggregator>

    <int-http:outbound-channel-adapter channel="postCompletion"
                                       url=" https://download.com/files/{filename}"
                                       http-method="DELETE">
    </int-http:outbound-channel-adapter>`

I think the other way is to invoke a bean during aggregator step and delete the file there, but above seems more cleaner, is it?

Comment: I thought you want to use JPA, so an aggregator input should be like this `afterSaving`, not the same for you JPA. Yes you can remove file in aggregation function, but that isn't its responsibility. So, a new component in the end

Comment: Thanks, that was a mistake, the input channel should be `afterSaving`. Also is it possible to wrap around from getting the file (in http outbound gateway) to deleting the file (in http outbound adapter) in a transaction?, so that if any of the steps failed in between before coming to deletion, the file would not be deleted?

Comment: Well, if you keep everything single-threaded, including splitter, you can use transactionSynchronizationFactory on the poker: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.8.RELEASE/reference/html/transactions.html#transaction-synchronization

Comment: I have used a header enricher before the http gateway to store the filename in header `<int:header-enricher>
            <int:header name="filename" expression="payload"/>
        </int:header-enricher>`, but for some reason `headers.filename` is not found after the aggregator. It was available up until the aggregator. So the component to delete the file after the aggregator fails as it can't see the `filename` header value. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: I don't see an aggregator configuration in your code snippet, so it isn't obvious how it is going. You can switch on `DEBUG` for the `org.springframework.integration` category to track messages. And you can share logs here with me to see headers before an aggregator and after. If that is a concern.